# class named 'User' , error : 'object has no attribute' for any method

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a class like this in my models

```
class User(ndb.Model):

    username = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    password_hash = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password_hash)
```

When I try to call it

```
user = User(username = _username)
user.hash_password(_password)
```

it gives error

```
'User' object has no attribute 'hash_password'
```

Am I doing some blunder here ?

#### UPDATE

The problem is with the class name `User` , changing it to some other name works fine. May be its conflicting with the GAE Model User.

Comment: User has 'hash_password' method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding an answer it might useful to others

The problem is with the class name `User` , changing it to some other name works fine. May be its conflicting with the GAE Model User.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Maybe you have an indentation error (e.g mixing tabs with spaces) in your original code.